# Error in reset password using laravel 5.2.(final step)

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, change-password

**working part:**

Forgot password link is working.

Reset password link is sent to email is working.

Redirecting to reset password page is working .

**Not working part:**

when clicking on reset password button, following error occurs:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

**My UserController:**

```
      public function forget(){

    if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {

    $checkemail=User::forget($_POST['email']);
    if($checkemail[0]){
            $sendemail =  Mail::send('emails.reset', ['code' => $checkemail[1]->code], function($message) {
        $message->to(Input::get('email'))
            ->subject('Password Reset');});


        return redirect()->back();

    }
    else{\Session::flash('message','Email  not found'); return redirect()-   >back();}
}
    else{

    return view('forget');}


}

public function reset($code=null)
{



            return view('resetpass')->with('code',$code);
            //$checkcode=User::reset($code);

}



public function resetpwd()
{

        $resetpwd = User::resetpwd(Input::all());

        if($resetpwd){echo "updated";}
}
```

**My model User.php:**

```
                 public static function forget($email)
 {
$emailpar=DB::table('users')->where('email','=',$email)->first();
if($emailpar){return array(true,$emailpar);}
else {return array(false);}
      }

          public static function resetpwd($user)
    {
        $updatepassword = DB::table('users')->where('code' ,'=' , $user->code)->update('password' => $user->password);

        if($updatepassword){return true;}

        else{return false;}

         }
```

Comment: my view file:  ` <html>
<body>
<form url="resetpwd" method="post">{{ csrf_field() }}

<input type="password" value="POST" name="password">


<input type="hidden" name="confirmationcode" value="{{$code}}">


<input type="submit" value="reset password">
 
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Might help to include what is in your Routes.php file for this specific method call. To me, it seems you are missing `{{ method_field('PUT')}}`  or `{{ method_field('PATCH')}}` within your form.

Comment: @AndrewNolan my routes.php: `Route::get('/forget','UserController@forget');
  Route::post('forget','UserController@forget');
  Route::get('reset/{code}','UserController@reset');`